# React state not consistent when using delay

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component with another component inside it that I only want to show if the user is still hovering after a short delay.

So I wrote a couple handlers for `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseExit` to set a variable to show that its hovered. Then, after sleeping, if it's still hovered I want to set a second variable to show the element.

However, `hovered` is showing as `false` no matter what.  Why?

```js
    const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    console.log('hovered', hovered); // This shows the state correctly

    const handleEnter = () => {
        setHovered(true);
        sleep(2000).then(() => {
            console.log('checking', hovered); // This always shows false
            if (hovered) {
                setShow(true);
            }
        });
    }

    const handleExit = () => {
        setHovered(false);
        setShow(false);
    }
```

## Edit

Solution:

Replace sleep with a wrapped callback from `use-debounce` to prevent it from firing multiple times, and have the delay work still.

```js
    const ref = useRef(false);
    const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const handleHover = useDebouncedCallback(() => {
        if (ref.current) setShow(true);
        else setShow(false);
    }, 1000);

    useEffect(() => {
        ref.current = hovered;
    }, [hovered]);

    useEffect(() => {
        handleHover()
    }, [hovered]);
```

Comment: you need to wrap somethings in `useEffect`.

Comment: @DanielA.White when I move the whole of the sleep block into a useEffect with `hovered` in the dependency array, it uses the previous state of `hovered`, not the current state.  (So it's basically doing the mouse in/out effect, but with a delay).  A quick mouse in mouse out (0.25s total) makes it so that after 2 seconds, the element is visible for a split second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would recommend you to use useRef hook.

```
const hoveredRef = useRef(false);
const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    hoveredRef.current = hovered;
}, [hovered])

useEffect(() => {
    if (!hovered) return;

    sleep(2000).then(() => {
        console.log('checking', hoveredRef.current);
        if (hoveredRef.current) {
            setShow(true);
        }
}, [hovered])

const handleEnter = () => {
    setHovered(true);
}

const handleExit = () => {
    setHovered(false);
    setShow(false);
}
```

I didnt check it but should be ok, i dont have the rest of your code, sorry

Regarding your question Why:

```
    const handleEnter = () => {
        setHovered(true);
        sleep(2000).then(() => {
            console.log('checking', hovered); // This always shows false
            if (hovered) {
                setShow(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

SetHover that you are calling here does not change the variable immediately,  for all the code after this line in function it will still be `false`. And in the sleep.then function scope it still uses a closure-captured old "false" value.

And a little warning here, code above is not ideal, if you hover in-out 5 times within your 2 second delay - code inside sleep.then will fire 5 times successfully. But it is harmless in your case, in terms of behavior.

Comment: I replaced the sleep with a callback wrapped using `use-debounce` which prevented the repeat calls.